# How to find the Taylor expansion of $(1-x)\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ at x = 1 and the Taylor expansion of $(\frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(x)})^x$ at $+\infty$?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

The goal of the problem is to find the two limits:

$\lim_{x \to 1} \left(1-x\right)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(x)}\right)^x$. In order to find these limits, we must first find the Taylor expansion of the two functions at the corresponding x's. But I don't really know what I should do.

I know how what Taylor series are and how to use them on simple functions, I also know the rules of division, multiplication and composition of Taylor polynomials, but I got stuck here.

Please be as detailed as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: You do not need the complete Taylor series. You just need the first term or two.

Comment: For the first, let $x=y+1$ and work around $y=0$ which is much simpler. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*